# Значени всех выделенных чекбоксов в одно поле таблицы

Tags: joomla

Есть компонент для Joomla.
Есть поле дополнительной информации о товаре, например.
В админке есть чекбоксы с одинаковым параметром name(около 20)

Внимание! Вопрос!

Как замутить, чтобы значение выделенных чекбоксов попадали в одно поле дополнительной информации? P.S. Не хотелось бы создавать отдельное поле для кажлого чекбокса

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
 print_r($_POST["CheckBoxName"]);
?>
<form method="post">
<?
 for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
 {
   echo '<input type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxName[]" value="o'.$i.'">';
 }
?>
 <input type="submit" value="Послать!" name="test">
</form>
```

UPD:

```
 $str = implode (',' ,$_POST["CheckBoxName"]);
```

и именно $str добавлять в базу как строку(или преобразовать к чему вам там нужно);

Comment: Пробовал я так - в базу пишется значение последнего выбранного чека

Comment: а если разные value у чеков выставить? Value="o1",Value="o2"..... так делать не пробовал просто, всегда хватало Name="Name_$id"

Comment: value разные

Comment: Проверил, автор вы что то не то делаете) вот пример, код сейчас в ответ положу... http://flippant.ru/assistant/test.php

Comment: в базу ложится array. где-то в модели нужно посмотреть

Comment: А что по вашему должно лечь в базу как не array? если вы его туда пытаетесь запихнуть))))))